# UITextView Ignores Line Breaks When The Text Comes From Web Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I'm using a `SOAP` service in my iPhone application and getting some text values from my remote database. In this text values, I intend to use `\n` for line breaks. But when I set the text of my `UITextView` to this value, it simply ignores the line breaks and shows them in single line.

If I declare its text in my code like `myTextView.text = @"Break\me";` it works great. But when I call the text from service, it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?